# How to troubleshoot a hard crash on CopyFeatures_management()

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I have a script that uses `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(FEATURE_CLASS_SDE, FEATURE_CLASS_LOCAL)` to copy a feature class from our enterprise SDE to a local file geodatabase. For the most part, it works well. Occasionally, though, it fails in spectacular fashion.

when it fails, I get a message that states python stopped working with a minidump. That's it. I wrapped the line that performs the copy in a try...except to get more info but the exception is not caught.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this further?

ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 w/ QIP (Build 3300)

Update 1: When I run the script within PyCharm, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. When I call the script from a batch file, on the same workstation, the issue occurs. This workstation has 8GB RAM, plenty of HDD space available, and by watching Resource Monitor I don't see any indications we're even close to running low on resources. Python.exe is using about 300mb. There are 95k features in the this SDE FC.

Comment: If you could mention how those two variables are created it could give some clue to the problem. I could imagine potential issues (trying to place it in a feature class dataset with a different spatial reference, some weird SDE naming issue).  At any rate, in that try/except block you should write a log so you can see if there's a common link between the datasets that fail.

Comment: Ah, I misread, I see that the except block was not tripped anyway, so that log idea won't work.  Instead, I would write information about each feature class (number of fields, number of features, etc.) to a log file before you run the copy features operation (and .close() the file object so the information is saved before python crashes).  That way you can start to get a feel for why the crash happens.  Seems like it could be a memory issue (too many features, maybe?)...

Comment: If the exception is not caught (well, maybe you're looking for the wrong one) by arcpy.GetMessages() then it's likely to be a RDBMS error on the server side, check the database logs to see error messages. When specifying your connection for your SDE features has your credentials been saved? Are you trying to run this in ArcGis as a tool or from command line/python interpreter?

Comment: I've had similar experience with data that contained non ascii characters. I discovered some debuggers don't throw the error but running it in a batch job does. I think because windows uses ascii but IDLE and pyscripter uses utf-8

Answer (score 2):

If the crash doesn't happen when copying from a local geodatabase I'd start by looking at some aspects of the source geodatabase:

1. The Feature Class

Bad features can cause problems with exporting data, faults such as self-intersecting or unclosed polygons, rings in the wrong direction etc.. Most DBMS have a methods for validating the geometry of the features, such as Oracle's [SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_LAYER_WITH_CONTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#BGHIAAIF) procedure.

You could try running the export with a subset of the feature class, say in 500 feature batches by objectid to see if the failure is predicable and always on the same objectID.

2. Does the crash occur with different feature classes in the same ArcSDE Geodatabase ?
3. Is there anything in the ArcSDE and RDBMS logs ?

For example if you are using direct connect to ArcSDE you can check the [`sdedc_<dbms>.log` file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002n00000035000000) on your workstation for any errors encountered with the export - it's usually in your profile temp directory.

If using the ArcSDE Application Server it will have it's own logfile which the DBA/SysAdmin could pull out for you.

There are some pointers but may help you to find out where the problem is.

Comment: SDE will validate geometries on storage so theoretically there shouldn't be any bad/empty geometries. Good point to check the local logs though.

Comment: SDE **should** validate geometries on storage.. in practice I don't see it. We've recently had a feature service fail to sync because of geometry errors, even though the data was stored in an ArcSDE feature class. Worth checking at least.